# Alternative to EIP1167

Tags: solidity, factory, polygon

I have an EIP1167 factory contract on Polygon that I'm going to use to trigger the deployment of custom ERC20 tokens. Once deployed via the factory I want to map the tokens on Polygon's bridge in order to be able to transfer them cross-chain. As you might know, having the token mapping setup on Polygon's bridge requires the token contracts to be verified on both chains (on Etherscan and Blockscout). However, Polygon's Blockscout instance seems to not support EIP1167 (although the Blockscout version they run, 3.6.0-beta, has support for EIP1167 contracts it doesn't seem to be properly configured - eg. check out this EIP1167 contract that is not detected as an EIP1167 contract and has no option for reading the contract code: https://explorer-mumbai.maticvigil.com/address/0x5f473dabe0B31475607FAf6C163bCF0b100F40a2/transactions).

For this reason, I'm looking for alternatives to EIP1167. More specifically, I want the factory to work exactly as before (that is, have a deployed logic contract that acts as a draft for futher deployments - it's very important to be able to change the logic contract on the go and have further deployments use the updated logic contracts while old deployments keep using the old logic contract). Is there a way to do this? More specifically, how can I get the deployment bytecode of an already deployed contract and use it to trigger new deployments?